# Google Translate: Text-to-speech TTS output in mp3 from IME Pinyin input

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate, ime

Using Google Translate, it is possible to generate TTS mp3 audio files from English or Chinese input using a simple URL. For example,

URL for English TTS for the word "English":
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=English

URL for Chinese TTS for the word 中文:
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh_CN&q=中文

How can I do the same using IME Hanyu Pinyin with tonal notations as input? For example, I want to generate the audio TTS file for zhōng wén (instead of 中文).

I have searched high and low on this website for a solution but was not successful. I do apologise if I have overlooked a solution previously offered here. Thanks

Comment: Could you try to convert Pinyin to Chinese characters, and then pass these Chinese characters to Google Translate?